# How to do the mean with specific conditions from a table? matlab

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to get the mean/sum of cyclists on different bikeways when there is rainfall.

table of bikeways and the conditions

[image]

How would I try and get the mean of each column of bikeways when rainfall > 1?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/80331-is-there-a-way-to-get-matlab-to-filter-out-specific-rows-in-arrays) and [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html?requestedDomain=nl.mathworks.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [accessing data in a table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) is very helpful for this. For a given column/variable `var`, you can get the mean when the rainfall is greater than 1 like so:

```
meanValue = mean(combined_data.var(combined_data.rainfall > 1));
```

If you'd like to compute the means for a number of columns at once, such as for the first 26 columns, you can do this:

```
meanValues = mean(combined_data{combined_data.rainfall > 1, 1:26});
```

And `meanValues` will be a 1-by-26 row vector of mean values for each column.

Comment: Thank you, how would I be able to do a mean for each column which is in the same table as meanvalue?

Comment: @Allan: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have to do the mean for several bikeways with rainfall and is there a way to put all the means in the same table?

Comment: @Allan: I updated my answer. Is that second option what you were looking for?